# Magento: Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to update a attribute of all our products inside our Magento shop.
But when selecting all products and choosing to update attributes, I get this error.

Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is this something you want to be able to do regularly, or is this a one time thing?

Comment: @BSMP Well I do not use this often. But if there is solution to this fix this for always, I prefer that one.